# Track patches deployed in Salesforce

Tags: deployment, patch

Recently we have asked Salesforce team to look into one issue specific to one org. They have deployed a patch for same in that org. Is there any way, we can track the patches deployed by Salesforce team in the org.

Comment: Ideally it would be done by Unmanaged or Managed package if it contains any code or metadata. From setup, navigate to `Build` -> `Installed Packages` and check if there are any packages.

Comment: I've checked the installed packages. No recent changes are there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce mentions the current patch revision on [Salesforce Status](https://status.salesforce.com/status). Click on your pod and you'll see the revision at the top of the page:

> STATUS & MAINTENANCE
>
> NA6 RELEASE: SPRING '17 PATCH 20.3

You can view a specific patch revision using the Revision Index. Note that this page tends to lag behind Salesforce Status. For example, at the time of this answer, [SPRING '17 PATCH 20.3](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=206020300) shows no data, and the page claims that all instances are currently on patch 18.3. Also keep in mind that not all releases may disclose what was included. Here's a recent example that shows included fixes: [SPRING '17 PATCH 20.0](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_releases_view?release=206020000).

Typically, you'll get a link from Support when they tell you that feature/fix XYZ will be patched in a particular version; you can use those links to view the status of the patch.